# I was trying to make a program that sends comment under a youtube's video while a send_keys() problem suddenly appeard

Tags: python, xml, selenium, youtube, sendkeys

I have written this code, for send comments under a youtube video, but when I execute it, it gaves me this error (line 20, the line of `msg_box.send_keys(msg)`):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/isiac/PycharmProjects/webtest/youtube test.py", line 20, in <module>
    msg_box.send_keys(msg)
  File "C:\Users\isiac\PycharmProjects\webtest\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 477, in send_keys
    self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT,
  File "C:\Users\isiac\PycharmProjects\webtest\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\isiac\PycharmProjects\webtest\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\isiac\PycharmProjects\webtest\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

idk why, can you help me?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

again = str("yes")

while again == 'yes':
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=youtubevideo")
    driver.maximize_window()

    msg = input("write your message  ")
    count = int(input("send how much time you want to send it  "))

    input("ready and waiting  ")

    msg_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/ytd-app/div/ytd-page-manager/ytd-watch-flexy/div[4]/div[1]/div/ytd-comments/ytd-item-section-renderer/div[1]/ytd-comments-header-renderer/div[5]/ytd-comment-simplebox-renderer/div[1]/yt-formatted-string")

    for index in range(count):
        time.sleep(5)
        msg_box.send_keys(msg)
        time.sleep(5)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/ytd-app/div/ytd-page-manager/ytd-watch-flexy/div[4]/div[1]/div/ytd-comments/ytd-item-section-renderer/div[1]/ytd-comments-header-renderer/div[5]/ytd-comment-simplebox-renderer/div[3]/ytd-comment-dialog-renderer/ytd-commentbox/div/div[4]/div[5]/ytd-button-renderer[2]/a/paper-button").click

    again = str(input("do you want to do it again?  "))

    print("acknowledge")
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the *full text* of the traceback.

Comment: The reason for the error is pretty clear - the element selected by your XPath can't be interacted with. You'll need to re-analyze the page to find the correct one.

Comment: i have added the whole error

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code on my machine line by line, and the problem is that when the page is first loaded, the `msg_box` element is not loaded, so your first XPath query fails. The comment element doesn't load until the page is scrolled down. This behavior *may* be dependent on screen size, but I'm on a laptop and don't have a large monitor to test.

In order to scroll down so the comment box is enabled, modify your script like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys # needed to send END key
import time

again = "yes" # "yes is already a string

while again == "yes":
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=youtubevideo")
    driver.maximize_window()
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.END) # this is the important part

    msg = input("write your message  ")
    count = int(input("send how much time you want to send it  "))

    print("ready and waiting") # we don't need input() here

    msg_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/ytd-app/div/ytd-page-manager/ytd-watch-flexy/div[4]/div[1]/div/ytd-comments/ytd-item-section-renderer/div[1]/ytd-comments-header-renderer/div[5]/ytd-comment-simplebox-renderer/div[1]/yt-formatted-string")

    for index in range(count):
        time.sleep(5)
        msg_box.send_keys(msg)
        time.sleep(5)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/ytd-app/div/ytd-page-manager/ytd-watch-flexy/div[4]/div[1]/div/ytd-comments/ytd-item-section-renderer/div[1]/ytd-comments-header-renderer/div[5]/ytd-comment-simplebox-renderer/div[3]/ytd-comment-dialog-renderer/ytd-commentbox/div/div[4]/div[5]/ytd-button-renderer[2]/a/paper-button").click()

    again = input("do you want to do it again?  ") # input() always returns a str

    print("acknowledge")
```

I didn't actually sign in to YouTube and leave a comment on a random video, so I don't know if your second XPath is valid, but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: ok, it doesn't work :/ I always scroll down before the input ready and waiting (its function is actually that: it blocks the program until the page is ready)

Comment: @lacops You may want to look into using the [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3), in particular the [`commentThreads/insert`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/insert) functionality. A quick Google search found a couple Python modules, but I don't know if they implement this particular functionality, so you might need to use `requests` to interact with it directly.

Comment: @lacops That being said, what exactly do you mean when you say "it doesn't work"? Does it give the same error as before? A different one? If it's different, please edit your question and post the full text of the error so we can debug it.